# Marker is not moving with realtime latitude and longitude angular google maps

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am trying to move marker in my Angular google map at realtime but it is not updating.it only gets first time static data and then it is not working I have searched google but nothing work for me.Here is my app.component.ts,

```
export class AppComponent {
title = "app";
lat: number = 33.738045;
lng: number = 73.084488;
constructor() {
let eventSource = window["EventSource"];
var urlToChangeStream ="http://192.168.100.7:3000/api/places/change-stream?_format=event-stream";
var src = new eventSource(urlToChangeStream);
src.addEventListener("data", function(msg) {
  var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
  this.lat =data.data.latitude;
  this.lng = data.data.longitude;
});
}
```

And this is my app.component.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is this

```
 src.addEventListener("data", function(msg) => { //adding arrow function
  var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
  this.lat =data.data.latitude;
  this.lng = data.data.longitude;
});
```

I think `this.lat` in your event listener is a different context than the `this.lat` in your component. The arrow function should let the function inherit the parent context.

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is your object structure. you have `data.data.latitude` so that means your object would be `msg.data.data.latitude`. If that is correct, then maybe throw a console.log(data) into there to see that your listener is actually firing. Also, small thing is it should be `let data` not `var data`.

Comment: yes data.data.latitude means msg.data.data.latitude. I have logged data and it is working perfectly fine. When I assign latitude and longitude to this.lat and this.lng it also logs fine but marker is not moving.

Comment: I guess make sure you are passing in the correct type into your lat/lng values? Otherwise I can't do much else without a plnkr/codepen example.

Comment: I have sent my lat,lng as parameter and then changed it.It was changing but then I got another issue so I gave up and moved to google javascript maps and achieved my goal.

Answer (score -1):

### Your Problem

```
JSON.parse(msg.data); <--- String
```

but

```
[latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" <--- Number
```

### Your Fix

```
this.lat = parseFloat(data.data.latitude)
```

That's it you are done.